# Where should I store common function at?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have three models.

- users_controllers.rb
- communities_controller.rb
- community_tipics_controller.rb

I'm using the function called **check_digit**

```
def checkdigit
 (transaction)
end
```

and I'm placing this in all the controllers.and calling it by before_filter.
But I think I'm wasting because I'm just pasting exactly the same code above to all of the controllers.

Where am I supposed to put it if my controller is using it in common?
Should I put it in controllers/application_controller.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this , some possible ways are (If I'm to do this)

**1st method**

If this is a simple method used by controllers 
inside application_controller.rb

```
private
def checkdigit
 (transaction)
end
```

**2nd method**

if your function is used by a specific category , (this is normally I do very often), create a separate controller and have your all other controllers inherited by it

Ex: if your method used only my admins, and assuming you have some more methods like that

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
   layout 'admin'

   private
   def checkdigit
     (transaction)
   end

end

and

class UsersController < AdminController

end
```

**3rd method**

If your method is/will used by models/controllers etc.. consider making it a module

```
module CommonMethods
   def checkdigit
     (transaction)
   end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
    include CommonMethods 
end
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in `helpers/application_helper.rb`

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, all common methods that all controllers need should be stored in the `ApplicationController`.

Furthermore, you should also keep common logic between all controllers in this controller.

**Edit:**
If they are just helpers, then you would put them where the helpers go, see the answer by @simone.